# Different databases for different apps in Django

Tags: python, django

I have multiple apps in my Django site: *mainsite*, *blog* and *tutorials*.

Can I use different databases (e.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL) in different Django apps?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970872/how-to-use-a-different-database-per-application-instance-in-django ; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is what you will have to do to get going.

1. Update settings for databases that you want to use.

**`settings.py`**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/var/db/projectdb'
}
'db_app1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/var/db/app1db'
}
'db_app2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/var/db/app2db'
}
```

2. For each database, implement a database router that will route the queries appropriately. In your case implement in each app. Note this more or less taken from django docs.

**`dbRouter.py`** (place in 'app1' folder):

```py
# DB router for app1
class App1DBRouter(object):
        """
    A router to control db operations
    """
    route_app_labels = {'app1'}
    db_name = 'db_app1'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to self.db_name.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return self.db_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to self.db_name.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return self.db_name
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        self.db_name database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == self.db_name
        return None
```

3. Update `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in settings.py

**`settings.py`**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.dbRouter.App1DBRouter', 'app2.dbRouter.App2DBRouter']
```

Comment: Is that all . i mean when i create models from admin , will they automatically get saved in second database. or i do need to do more things for admin

Comment: You need to do syncdb, I think you may have to do reset if DBs are already present.

Comment: I would like to suggest to change the name of the db from 'app1' to db_app1 for distinguishing when should the db name be used, and when should the app be used.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão, agree and updated, thanks.

Comment: where does the app1.dbRouter.py lives? at the application level? or at the project level?

Comment: @Marcel, the name `app1.dbRouter.py` suggests that it lives in app level.

Comment: In `allow_relation` shouldn't it check that both models are in "app1" (`and` instead of `or`)?

Comment: I created a reusable class for this: https://gist.github.com/antonagestam/971461a98689efe7938d

Comment: Will this still use the default DB for models not caught by the app1 and app2 routers?

Comment: From the docs, `If you left your default database empty and don’t want to define a catch-all database router to handle all apps not otherwise specified, your routers must handle the names of all apps in INSTALLED_APPS before you migrate.`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers). I am inclined to think so @RickWestera.