# Share models between multiple apps and multiple database without code duplication (django)

Tags: python, django

I'm currently developing a web app in Django. My app is dealing with vegetables and gardens. A garden can have its own vegetables, but I would like it to be able to import vegetables from a common library/encyclopedia.

[Diagram of the models in the main app and in the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlUL.png)

A first idea was to have a garden_id for all vegetables and set it to 0 or None for vegetables of the library but then the library isn't really reusable and is tightly coupled to the main app.

A second idea was that vegetables linked to garden inherit from vegetables from library, but inheritance tends to be tricky with Django.

A last idea that I use for the moment, is to create a second django app for the vegetable library and duplicate the vegetable model (in the main and the library app).

I plan to implement an "import" module, that would convert vegetables from the library to vegetables linked to a garden.

I also have two databases, one for the main app and one containing the common vegetables ( [Can i use different databases for different apps in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756356/can-i-use-different-databases-for-different-apps-in-django/13756801#13756801) )

Duplication is never a good idea, but I can't find a good and easy way to solve this problem (which seems simple).